# Add a button on top of keyboard when called

Tags: react-native, expo

Im trying to see if I can add a button on top of the keyboard when its called i've seen this feature in many apps but not sure if its possible on expo and react-native. the button should appear with the keyboard and become invisible when the pressed or the keyboard goes away. Ive put a my sample class that goes with the added image  [image: Example]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
View,
TextInput
} from 'react-native';

export default class test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 this.state = {
  a: props.navigation,
  b: '',
 }
}

componentWillMount() {

  }


render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={{marginTop: 300,marginLeft: 50,borderWidth: 1}}
    placeholder="type"
    />
  </View>
 );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  paddingTop: 22,
  backgroundColor: '#42444f',
},

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach

```
constructor(props)
{
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     buttonVisible: false // add this state. this state is the flag for button appearance
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow,
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this._keyboardDidHide,
    );
  }

 _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonVisible: true
    })
  }

  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonVisible: false
    })
  }

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
       <TextInput
         style={{marginTop: 300,marginLeft: 50,borderWidth: 1}}
       placeholder="type"
       />
     </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {this.state.buttonVisible ? <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}><Text>Button</Text></TouchableOpacity> : <View/>}
    </View>
  </View>
 );
}
```

the button will be visible depending on the `buttonVisible` state value, the state changed inside the keyboard event listener that initialized in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thanks for this I do get an error that this.setState is undefined when the keyboard is called

Comment: try use es6 arrow function for _keyboardDidShow and _keyboardDidHide and call inside the componentDidMount with () in the end of the call, eg : this._keyboardDidShow()